How to unnest data from one column to fit the entire dataset - Google Sheets
I'm trying to unnest data in one column separated by " | ". The rest of the columns should "follow" the unnested logic from that column.
I've made a sample spreadsheet to summarise my problem.
Found a similar problem here but could not replicate it for my use-case.
Also I do have in my original spreadsheet 50 columns so I'm not sure this is the right approach.
Thanks in advance for any help.
edit: Added a blank cell in the table

Try this Solution
The unnest data where the "Date" column contains multiple date values separated by " | ", and each row in the table should be expanded to multiple rows, one for each date.
It also ensures that the "name", "last name", and "email" columns follow the unnested logic for each date.
Note : Kindly update the Column for the Date time format after pasting the formula.
Updated Formula used
=BYROW(SORT(TOCOL(BYROW(B2:E6, LAMBDA(r, let(x, CHOOSECOLS(r,1,2,3), y,CHOOSECOLS(r,4), z, if(y <> "", SPLIT(y,"|"),""), TOROW(BYROW(TOCOL(z),LAMBDA(c, JOIN("|",x,c))))))))), LAMBDA(m, IFERROR(SPLIT(m, "|"),"")))

Sample Output

References

BYROW
TOCOL
CHOOSEROW


Thanks for your reply! Very concise and clear approach. It works on my sample spreadsheet but when I tested on my actual spreadsheet, it did not work as expected due to some cells having blank values. I tried to twist it to handle blank cells but it doesn't look that straightforward.

Hi @Damien, I updated my answer based on your request. Kindly check  if it met your expected result.
